# How to get parent AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I need to do something like this in c# (pseudo):

```
static var ns = new Non_Serializable_Nor_Marshal()

var app = new AppDomain();
app.execute(foo)

void foo()
{
    var host = AppDomain.Current.Parent; //e.g. the original one
    host.execute(bar)
}

void bar()
{
    ns.Something();
}
```

IOW I have a non serializeable nor marshal object in one appdomain. 
I want to create a second domain and execute foo(). From within that second domain I want to execute bar() on the original domain.

How do I pass the original domain to the child one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use interop, you can also use a little trick using AppDomainManager. You can basically automatically 'wire' the 'primary' domain into any domains automatically - albiet the way I do it means you discard your real primary domain.

Here is the class that does all the magic:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a <see cref="AppDomainManager"/> that is
/// aware of the primary application AppDomain.
/// </summary>
public class PrimaryAppDomainManager : AppDomainManager
{
    private static AppDomain _primaryDomain;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the primary domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The primary domain.</value>
    public static AppDomain PrimaryDomain
    {
        get
        {
            return _primaryDomain;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the primary domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="primaryDomain">The primary domain.</param>
    private void SetPrimaryDomain(AppDomain primaryDomain)
    {
        _primaryDomain = primaryDomain;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the primary domain to self.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetPrimaryDomainToSelf()
    {
        _primaryDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this is the primary domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <see langword="true"/> if this instance is the primary domain; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
    public static bool IsPrimaryDomain
    {
        get
        {
            return _primaryDomain == AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the initial domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="friendlyName">Name of the friendly.</param>
    /// <param name="securityInfo">The security info.</param>
    /// <param name="appDomainInfo">The AppDomain setup info.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AppDomain CreateInitialDomain(string friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager is PrimaryAppDomainManager)
            return null;

        appDomainInfo = appDomainInfo ?? new AppDomainSetup();
        appDomainInfo.AppDomainManagerAssembly = typeof(PrimaryAppDomainManager).Assembly.FullName;
        appDomainInfo.AppDomainManagerType = typeof(PrimaryAppDomainManager).FullName;

        var appDomain = AppDomainManager.CreateDomainHelper(friendlyName, securityInfo, appDomainInfo);
        ((PrimaryAppDomainManager)appDomain.DomainManager).SetPrimaryDomainToSelf();
        _primaryDomain = appDomain;
        return appDomain;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a new or existing application domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="friendlyName">The friendly name of the domain.</param>
    /// <param name="securityInfo">An object that contains evidence mapped through the security policy to establish a top-of-stack permission set.</param>
    /// <param name="appDomainInfo">An object that contains application domain initialization information.</param>
    /// <returns>A new or existing application domain.</returns>
    /// <PermissionSet>
    ///     <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="ControlEvidence, ControlAppDomain, Infrastructure"/>
    /// </PermissionSet>
    public override AppDomain CreateDomain(string friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
    {
        appDomainInfo = appDomainInfo ?? new AppDomainSetup();
        appDomainInfo.AppDomainManagerAssembly = typeof(PrimaryAppDomainManager).Assembly.FullName;
        appDomainInfo.AppDomainManagerType = typeof(PrimaryAppDomainManager).FullName;

        var appDomain = base.CreateDomain(friendlyName, securityInfo, appDomainInfo);
        ((PrimaryAppDomainManager)appDomain.DomainManager).SetPrimaryDomain(_primaryDomain);

        return appDomain;
    }
}
```

And you need to alter your `Main()` (application entry) slightly:

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program().Run(args);
}

void Run(string[] args)
{
    var domain = PrimaryAppDomainManager.CreateInitialDomain("PrimaryDomain", null, null);
    if (domain == null)
    {
        // Original Main() code here.
    }
    else
    {
        domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap<Program>().Run(args);
    }
}
```

Now at any point you can get `PrimaryAppDomainManager.PrimaryDomain` to get a reference to the primary domain, just remember that it isn't the inital domain created by the .Net runtime - it's one we create immediately.

You can look at the comments in my [blog post](http://jonathan.dickinsons.co.za/blog/2010/11/cross-domain-singleton-in-c/) for an way to get the .Net runtime to hook this in for you automatically using the app.config.

Edit: I forgot to add the extension method I use, here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new instance of the specified type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to create.</typeparam>
/// <param name="appDomain">The app domain.</param>
/// <returns>A proxy for the new object.</returns>
public static T CreateInstanceAndUnwrap<T>(this AppDomain appDomain)
{
    var res = (T)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(T));
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try referencing mscoree and then using its methods. I have used this in one of my projects.
mscoree will keep track of your AppDomains without any input.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the primary application domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The primary application domain.</returns>
    public static AppDomain GetPrimaryAppDomain()
    {
        return GetAppDomain(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the application domain with the given friendly name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="friendlyName">The friendly name of the application domain.</param>
    /// <returns>The application domain with the given friendly name.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">Thrown if friendlyName is null.</exception>
    public static AppDomain GetAppDomain(string friendlyName)
    {
        if (friendlyName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("friendlyName");
        }
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        CorRuntimeHostClass host = new CorRuntimeHostClass();
        try
        {
            host.EnumDomains(out handle);
            object domain = null;
            while (true)
            {
                host.NextDomain(handle, out domain);
                if (domain == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                AppDomain appDomain = (AppDomain)domain;
                if (appDomain.FriendlyName == friendlyName)
                {
                    return appDomain;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            host.CloseEnum(handle);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(host);
            host = null;
        }
    }
```

(Adapted from http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2007/05/18/cross-appdomain-singleton.aspx)