# Two-way communication between AppDomains inside of IIS Requests

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm working on an ASP.NET app, and we want to add the ability to call customer script during some of the requests.  Since we don't trust this script, we are spawning a child AppDomain inside of our IIS request which has limited permissions, and loading both the customer assembly and a Script Runner assembly.  The customer script can do things like change the description of a business object or change a status code to an error if certain criteria are met.  Because the changes are so varied, I can't encompass them in a single object that gets returned from a method call.  As the script is running, I need it to alter values in objects inside of the Request that launched this child.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972352/communication-between-appdomains) recommends using NetNamedPipeBinding, but I'm growing concerned that it isn't appropriate for code running inside of IIS where multiple requests could be running concurrently.  Would I set up a new host for each IIS request?  Set up a static host for the entire process, and then use endpoints to make sure that the correct child talks with the correct request?  Is this the right technology?

If this isn't the right technology, what is?  This [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48119559-0a6c-4367-b34b-1e0826429a77/finding-the-default-appdomain-of-a-process-from-child-appdomain?forum=csharpgeneral) tells you how to retrieve the handle of the parent AppDomain, but many of those seem to use mscoree.dll, and generally I was under the impression that COM and IIS didn't mix terribly well.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120866/how-to-get-parent-appdomain) talks about wiping out your initial AppDomain and creating a new one.  Perhaps that's not necessary in IIS?

Is there a way for a child AppDomain to efficiently execute methods inside of the Request object that spawned it, and if so what is it?

Comment: Ever find a solution?  I'm struggling with AppDomain communication in IIS as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've found a simple technique for a child **AppDomain** to alter the state in the parent **AppDomain** without using WCF or mscoree.dll.  Rereading the first post above, I see he does mention it as a possibility, but rejects it for reasons that are not clear to me.  The trick is to create an object derived from **MarshalByRefObject** in the parent, obtain an **ObjectHandle** to it, and then pass that **ObjectHandle** to the child **AppDomain**.  The child can then unwrap the handle to get a proxy, and can then call methods which will alter the state of the object in the parent.  Here's a code sample:

```
class Program
{
    public class ParentFacade : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public List<string> Collection { get; set; }
        public void AddElement(string el)
        {
            Collection.Add(el);
        }
    }

    public class ChildFacade : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void AlterParentState(ObjectHandle handle)
        {
            var parent = handle.Unwrap() as ParentFacade;
            parent.AddElement("Message from child");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var child = AppDomain.CreateDomain("child");
        var childFacadeType = typeof(ChildFacade);
        var childProxy = child.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(childFacadeType.Assembly.FullName, childFacadeType.FullName) as ChildFacade;

        var parentColl = new List<string>();
        var facade = new ParentFacade();
        facade.Collection = parentColl;
        var facadeHandle = new ObjectHandle(facade);
        childProxy.AlterParentState(facadeHandle);

        foreach (var item in parentColl)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

This code shows that a method in the child was able to alter the state of objects in the parent.  This particular example isn't terribly useful, but this is very powerful when you are setting up a sandbox, and include .dll's in the child assembly that you don't trust.  The untrusted assembly can call methods in the ChildFacade and thereby alter the state in the parent in a controlled and safe way.